# How to Pass value as dynamic array from vb to c

Tags: c, arrays, vba, vb6

I have below declaration:

```
Type routineStruct
  man As String * 3
  number As String * 5
End Type

Type vbToC
  sch As String * 4
  routine(0 To 10000) As routineStruct
End Type

vbfun As vbToC
```

Now we are sending this vbfun As vbToC from VB to C.
Now for above vbToC type , 64K memory limit error is occuring while compiling.
So, we use the dynamic array as like -

```
Type vbToC
  sch As String * 4
  routine() As routineStruct
End Type
```

And then assign value

```
Redim routine(10000)
For loop = 0 To 10000
  .routine(loop).man = value1
  .routine(loop).number = value2
Next
```

My question is above vbToc declaration for dynamic array is right or not? if right then can it be possible to send values from vb to c with this dynamic array and how to receive the value for dynamic array for each structure element?

Comment: I think we need some language clarification; you have several versions of VB mentioned there, and do you mean C, C++ or C#?

Comment: And what will this "C" be? A DLL? Or a separate process?

Comment: I am using vb6 and that is a c dll

Comment: If this not possible to send values using dynamic array then can i use byte array? And for byte array ,what will be coding for both vb and c

Comment: VB arrays are not really arrays, they are struct of SAFEARRAY. you have to google SAFEARRAY, and it worth you study it.

Comment: you have to provide the c definition of `vbToC` type. is vbToC member (routine) dynamic array or static array?

Answer (score 0):

In VB6 the type you have defined as "routineStruct" is invalid. You would most certainly receive a compile error here. If you are trying to declare "man" and "number" as arrays the syntax is not correct. You would need to use a declaration similar to your "routine" element with an array declaration.

Furthermore, you have declared your type without any access modifier. When you do this it will default to "private." If you were to export the VB6 ActiveX DLL to a type library for use in C++ the type would therefore not be visible and marshaling would not be possible.

The solution would be to adjust your type declaration to include proper VB6 syntax as well as make the type public. Marshaling of native string types become BSTR in C/C++ and you should have no problem here.